# Laravel 5.2 - If Isset Not working in blade

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do something like this-

```
<select name="project_type_id" class="form-control select-styled">
   <option value=0>Please Select a Project Type</option>
   @foreach ($project_types as $project_type)
       <option
            @if ( isset( Request::old('project_type_id') ) )
                strcmp(Request::old('project_type_id'),$project_type->id) ? "" : 'selected'
            @else
                strcmp($current_project->project_type_id,$project_type->id) ? "" : 'selected'
            @endif
           value="{{ $project_type->id }}">
           {{ $project_type->name }}
       </option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

In Blade Template Engine.

But I am getting some error like this-

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Don't use isset()  with Request::old('project_type_id')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile Error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636880/compile-error-cannot-use-isset-on-the-result-of-an-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory.  This is not specific to blade. The function [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is used to determine if a variable has been set, you are checking a function call.

You don't need the isset(), just use:

```
@if ( Request::old('project_type_id') )
```

Comment: what if `project_type_id` was `0`

Comment: @lagbox Then you'd have to check if not null or the string length, both of which will work on this function call unlike isset.